# creating pointer to a vector, in a class

Tags: c++, vector

I am creating a CAD software in which I have a class **point** & a class **line**.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class point
{
private:
    vector<int>* child;
    int id;//this is unique id of a point
    double x;//absolute x, y, z co-ord
    double y;//
    double z;//
};

class line
{
private:
    point *a;
    point *b;
    int id;//this is unique for each line object
}
```

any line object is the child of 2 point objects.
so if i delete a point of a line then the line object shud also be deleted.
For this i want to store the *id* of all children (line, circle, triangle,....) of a point object in a vector *child* (instance variable of class point as shown in code).

my question is is my approach correct?
i mean that, there will be around 100's of point objects in an execution.
since each vector allocates some extra memory, there will be a lot of allocated memory which will not be used in an execution.
can anybody suggest an alternative way of storing unknown no of *int* as a sequence in each point object?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. However to use vector you have first to "#include <vector>" and then writing somewhere "using namespace std;"

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti never do `using namespace x` in a header file in global scope.

Comment: Yes true :) i agree sorry. He should do std::vector<int>

Comment: Perhaps are you asking us the concept of reference counting? I don't understand the question still.

Comment: i am creating the point object dynamically. so i just wanted to know whether my approach is good or is there a better method (in terms of memory) to store unknown no of _int_ as instance variable, as each vector consumes some extra memory & so due to the many point objects that i will have there will be a lot of memory wastage

Comment: @salvatore i think i have made the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is how do i create this vector & where (so that it doesnt go out of scope)?

You have already done this correctly. I'd suggest that you dont't use a pointer to your `vector` but simply a `vector` itself:

```
private:
    vector<int> child;
```

This makes handling it much easier, and you don't have to allocate/deallocete it by yourself.

---

> how do i make my child point to the created vector without memory leak?

If you really need to have a dynamically allocated pointer, you have to call `new` and `delete`. For this to behave correctly, you have to define both a constructor and a destructor in your `point` class:

```
class point
{
private:
    point() : child(new vector<int>) {}
    ~point() { delete child; }

    vector<int>* child;
    int id;//this is unique id of a point
    double x;//absolute x, y, z co-ord
    double y;//
    double z;//
};
```

But I still recommend that you don't use a pointer to a `vector` as I have explained above.

Comment: can you suggestany alternative for vectors; because there will be a lot of memory wastage during the program execution

Comment: `vectors` typically have a small memory overhead and are usually quite efficient unless you insert/delete many items.

Comment: suppose each vector has 32 byte of excess memory, then 100 * 32 = 3200byte of waste memory for a single class....likewise there are around 30 other classes...how much memory will be wasted!!!

Comment: @CAD_coding: [check boost `array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/array.html)

Comment: @CAD_coding: are you really targetting such a low-memory device that it's worth putting effort into saving a handful of kilobytes? If so, you should mention it in the question. If not, then don't worry about the overhead of using `vector`.

Comment: @CAD_coding: The waste of memory in a `vector` is implementation and use dependent. Typical implementations grow the double of their previous size, when their space is exceeded. If you know, that your `child` field will not exceed a certain size you can use `std::vector` with no doubt. An option would be to use `std::list` (or `std::slist`) where you have a fixed waste of memory for every element. Also you can check Naszta's tip to use `boost::array`, which gives you a fixed sized array.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a pointer to a vector, an object would do:

```
#include <vector>
class point
{
private:
   std::vector<int> child;
   int id;//this is unique id of a point
   double x;//absolute x, y, z co-ord
   double y;//
   double z;//
};
```

Don't forget to include `<vector>` and qualify your use with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem in a totally different way.

I would keep two global hashtables by id: one for points and one for lines.
Then i would use a doubly linked list data structure for each point so that you know how many lines are using a given point.

I would make the access to these data structure easy through simple operations in a global container class.

I'll try to write some "pseudo" code to make it clearer (editing soon).